# Categorize text using nltk

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I am new in NLP concepts. I need to categorize my mails in my inbox to bills, health, ads etc. I am planning to use nltk to categorize and read that nltk.classify.naivebayes is a good choice for it. Where do I start? Can anyone give me a simple sample code. I have seen a lot of post which explains naivebayes and its algorithm.

Comment: First step would be to annotate your data.

Comment: Second (or even first) step is to read the chapter on classification in the NLTK book.

Comment: @JosepValls How do I annotate data? Can you pls provide an example code?

Answer (score -2):

First, as already mentioned, you should annotate your data. That means assigning tags (e.g. bills, health) to the e-mails you already have in your inbox. 
Afterwards, you have to normalize it, that means splitting it into tokens and turning all words to lower case.

To start working with the data, it has to be represented as vectors in dictionaries.

Here is also a good [Tutorial](http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/blogger/2010/12/07/naive-bayes-classifier-in-50-lines/) I find pretty useful.

Comment: Don't write your own Naive Bayes classifier (which is what the tutorial is for). Use the one the nltk provides.